# How to prevent the default focus on text fields when using html5's placeholder attribute

Tags: jquery, forms, html

If I have a form with the placeholder attribute like so:

```
<input type="text" name="something" placeholder="username" />
<input type="text" name="somethingelse" placeholder="password" />
```

When I come to the page with the above form, by default the first text field is focused, i.e. has the cursor in it. This is a problem since I'm using the placeholder text as the labels for the text fields. So if the username field is focused that placeholder text isn't there leaving something confused as to what they should enter in that field.

Comment: I'm not convinced by any of the proposed solutions. Using the placeholder attribute, does not focus any special element. There must be a script involved, which is causing this focus behavior. Instead of adding another focus-away script. You should find the script and see, how you can change it's behavior. There might be a config-option or other possibilities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could force focus to something else through javascript

```
jQuery(function($){
  $(".someotherelement").focus();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can always `autofocus="autofocus"` other input element (if there is submit input for example).
Also you can do `<body onLoad="document.some-other-element.focus()">`

Comment: This would have been the better solution but I had to use js since the form is inside simple modal, also I had to use blur and not focus, which for some reason wasn't working on the submit field. So I just blured the focused element "onShow" which is a simple modal callback.

Comment: I'm not convinced that this is the better solution; this violates unobtrusive design as we're sticking control elements into the html; of course, I suppose whether page focus is a controller function is subjective...

Comment: I agree about the `onload` part, however setting the focus by an html attribute is more unobtrusive than using javascript for that.